# Is there a trick that let's one "pass a namespace" into a template?

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces

### The Scenario:

Let's say we have several libraries, each in their own namespace, each containing the exact same set of classes and functions with the same API in every namespace. These libraries have absolutely no knowledge of one another and share no common bases.

```cpp
namespace A {
class Foo { ... };
class Bar { ... };
class Baz { ... };
// A dozen more types
};

namespace B {
class Foo { ... };
class Bar { ... };
class Baz { ... };
// A dozen more types
};

namespace C {
class Foo { ... };
class Bar { ... };
class Baz { ... };
// A dozen more types
};
```

I am in no way defending this design, but let's take it as a constraint that can't be changed. There are clearly better ways of doing this, but I'm not at liberty to change that right now.

### The Problem:

Given the above, we often want implement higher level code that makes use of these libraries, but we don't want to have to repeat this code for each one. Templates seem like the obvious solution.

```cpp
template<typename Foo, typename Bar, typename Baz>
class FooBarBazzer
{
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo;
    std::vector<Bar> bars;
    Baz baz;
    ...
}
```

This doesn't look too bad, but it requires us to list `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz` as template parameters and as the number of types involved has grown, this has quickly lead to some seriously unwieldy template argument lists.

I find myself wanting the following imaginary syntax:

```cpp
template<namespace ns>
class FooBarBazzer
{
    std::unique_ptr<ns::Foo> foo;
    std::vector<ns::Bar> bars;
    ns::Baz baz;
    ...
}
```

One potential workaround is to write and maintain a trait `struct` for each namespace containing a member type for every type in that namespace.

```
namespace A {
struct Types {
    using Foo = A::Foo;
    using Bar = A::Bar;
    using Baz = A::Baz;
    // A dozen more type aliases
};
}

namespace B {
struct Types {
    using Foo = B::Foo;
    using Bar = B::Bar;
    using Baz = B::Baz;
    // A dozen more type aliases
};
}

namespace C {
struct Types {
    using Foo = C::Foo;
    using Bar = C::Bar;
    using Baz = C::Baz;
    // A dozen more type aliases
};
}

template<typename Types>
class FooBarBazzer
{
    std::unique_ptr<typename Types::Foo> foo;
    std::vector<typename Types::Bar> bars;
    typename Types::Baz baz;
    ...
}
```

But that seems like a lot of boilerplate. (It's also a lot of `typename` keywords sprinkled around, which isn't ideal, but I doubt that's avoidable.)

### The Question:

Is there some better trick to accomplish this? To tell a template at instantiation time which namespace it should be looking for types in? One that doesn't require writing and maintaining much boilerplate?

I suspect the answer is no, but I'm constantly amazed by the things that experts are able to make the C++ type system do.

Comment: Depending on how your actual impl of `DoAllFoosBar` looks, we might be able to get away with using a parameter pack instead of explicitly listing all types

Comment: Writing some type traits may help.

Comment: No, you can't do this. Templates work with types, not namespaces. If you want a 'god' type, you'd have to define a type which serves this purposes (and you mention this yourself). You can also use a MACRO, if you up to it.

Comment: Short answer is No, there is no way for a namespace to be passed to a template. However as you acknowledge in the question, this seems like something well-suited to just leveraging ADL. Is there any reason you would be unhappy with just constraining your `DoAllFoosBar` with SFINAE rather than trying to constrain to an entire namespace?

Answer (score 1):

### Short Answer

There is no way to pass a `namespace` to a `template`; however that doesn't mean that there aren't alternatives to your situation.

### Long Answer

Although there is no way to pass a `namespace` specifically to this, there is also no real reason why you can't support your use-case in a generic way. Your suggestion to use traits could definitely work -- but might be an unnecessary manual effort depending on the specifics of your problem.

You mention your concerns of growth for the number of types -- and this could be satisfied with a variadic argument list:

```cpp
template<typename Foo, typename Bar, typename...Args>
bool DoAllFoosBar(const std::vector<Foo> & foos, const Bar & bar, const Args&...args)
{
    return std::all_of(foos.begin(),
                       foos.end(),
                       [&](const auto & foo){ return IsFooBar(foo, bar, args...); });
}
```

As long as 1 of the arguments matches something unambiguously from the `namespace` (which from the sounds of it, it should), it will still call through ADL-qualification -- it just now supports two *or more* arguments.

Additionally, although you cannot constrain strictly on the *namespace* itself -- you can constrain the function to only be invocable if `IsFooBar` is invocable on its arguments -- either through SFINAE or just `static_assert`.

For example:

```cpp
// Dummy definition in current scope, so it can find others through ADL
void IsFooBar();

template<typename Foo, typename Bar, typename...Args>
auto DoAllFoosBar(const std::vector<Foo> & foos, const Bar & bar, const Args&...args)
  -> decltype(IsFooBar(foos, bar, args...))
  // ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -- expression sfinae
{
  ...
}
```

This uses Expression SFINAE to conditionally enable `DoAllFoosBar` if and only if `IsFooBar(...)` produces a valid result. Since it also sees `IsFooBar` in the current scope, it will look for all valid entries through ADL as well. You could also do something similar to turn this into a `static_assert` as well.

Comment: In this case, the additional types I'm concerned about aren't function arguments at all but named members of larger objects. So variadic templates aren't really going to help at all. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If that's the case, then you should add that to the question. It's impossible to provide an answer to a question that lacks all the details. But from what you just described, the same can be achieved with pointers-to-members to extract the desired members as needed.

Comment: I've updated my example to make it a bit more complicated and demonstrate why variadic template arguments aren't enough.

I was unclear before. These types are _used_ as member objects in generic code, so it's not something that pointers-to-members can fix.